# Как запретить сжатие блока по ширине при фиксированном позиционировании?

Tags: css

Есть блок с фиксированным позиционированием (left: 50%):

```css
.bonus_window {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF005C 0%, #FFF500 100%);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.bonus_window_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: #071437;
}

.bonus_window_inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 36px 0 210px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 132px;
  position: relative;
}

.bonus_window .bonus_icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -134px;
  left: -82px;
}

.bonus_window .bonus_text {
  margin: 0 36px 0 0;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.bonus_window .bonus_button {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bonus_window js-bonus_window">
  <div class="bonus_window_wrapper">
    <div class="bonus_window_inner">
      <img class="bonus_icon" src="./img/gift_icon.png" alt="icon">
      <div class="bonus_text">You won <br> 250 free spins</div>
      <div class="bonus_button js-order_button">Get</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что если ширина блока по ширине больше 50%, то он начинает сжиматься.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы блок не сжимался, а уходил за край монитора? Конечно, можно родительскому блоку `.bonus_window` задать фиксированную ширину, но этот вариант не подходит, т.к. тексты будут подставляться разные.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink почитайте, может пригодиться

Comment: flex-shrink тут не помогает

Comment: Вы пробовали задавать `min-width:` вместо `width:` тому блоку?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать задать не фиксированную ширину, а min-width, чтобы блок не сжимался ниже какого-то фиксированного размера. А если он и уменьшится, то всё, что не влезет, будет за страницей. Но тут тогда возникнет горизонтальный скролл страницы, что вообще плохо для юзера. Поэтому также не забудь добавить для всей страницы overflow-x: hidden